# wpf xaml loop thru a gridview which is inside a listview and get the cell value

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, gridview

I have the following in my dgridtext.xaml file.

XAML

```
<Grid x:Name="grid1">
<StackPanel>
    <ListView Name="listview1" IsTextSearchEnabled="True" TextSearch.TextPath="Enquiry_Number">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView ColumnHeaderToolTip="Multiple Category Information">                        
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Enquiry_Number}" Header="Enquiry number"/>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Consignee_Ref}" Header="Consignee reference"/>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Booking_Reference}" Header="Booking reference"/>

            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>                
    </ListView>            
</StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Something like this.

dgridtest.xaml.cs

```
for (int i = 0; i < listview1.Items.Count; i++)
{
    MessageBox.Show(listview1.Items[i].ToString());            
}
```

But all that returns is System.Data.DataRowView

Please help.

Update:

In My dgridtextxaml.cs file, I call the DataManager.cs class passing a dataset object which is the source of my listview(listview1).

```
DataManager.BindFilteredData(dts);
listview1.ItemsSource = dts.Tables[0].DefaultView;
```

And this is what I have in my DataManager.cs class

```
    public static void BindFilteredData(DataSet dts)
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString))
        {
            string sql = "SELECT Enquiry_Number, Consignee_Ref, Booking_Reference FROM ConsHead";

            using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection))
            {                    
                adapter.Fill(dts);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cast the item to whatever class you use in the ListView and then use any property you need from it. Something like:

```
var item = listView1.Items[i] as YourClassHere;
```

**Edit**

In your case, since you bind the ItemsSource to a DataSet directly you probably can use DataRowView class, and then use the properties from it:

```
var firstItem = listview1.Items[0] as DataRowView;
var firstCellValue = firstItem.Row[0];
```

Comment: Hi Adrian - I was wondering if you could explain a little about the class used by my ListView. I'm not to clear about the use of classes. At the moment I databind my listview by using a class I called DataManager. Directly from SQL, no get set operators. Could you please give some example of how you would use a class for the listview?

Comment: So you use an SQL query and set the results directly on the ListView ? Maybe you can edit the question to show us how you populate the ListView, so we could try to find a solution that fits your needs.

Comment: I have updated my answer to include the databinding of the listview.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much Adrian. If you had any idea how I have been struggling with this and in the end it turned out to be two short lines of code. Thanks again.

Comment: It does not work for me. `var firstItem = listview1.Items[0]` returns first item from my collection, but as soon I declare `var firstItem = listview1.Items[0] as DataRowView` it returns `null`. In debugging I see it's an object. It always returns a classname where I declared bindings `{namespace.ClassName}`.